# uninstalling Atlas properly

Tags: 12.04, package-management, uninstall

If you have error that contain “gfortran” in it, like this one:

```
ImportError: (‘/home/Nick/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6.35-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-10.10-maverick–2.6.6/tmpIhWJaI/0c99c52c82f7ddc775109a06ca04b360.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done’
```

Hi, I am following given steps. 
The problem is probably that NumPy is linked with a different blas then then one currently available (probably ATLAS). There is 2 possible fixes:

```
Uninstall ATLAS and install OpenBLAS.
Use the Theano flag “blas.ldflags=-lblas -lgfortran”
```

1) is better as OpenBLAS is faster then ATLAS and NumPy is probably already linked with it. So you won’t need any other change in Theano files or Theano configuration.

But i dont how to uninstall this ATLAS package. 
I tried

```
 sudo apt-get remove libatlas
```

but it didnt worked. Can you tell me how can i formally remove them.
regards

Comment: You should uninstall atlas`sudo apt-get remove libatlas*`  and do `update-alternative` as explained below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the ATLAS development packages, they are actually called `libatlas-dev` and `libatlas-base-dev`.

However, there should be no need to uninstall these packages in order to use OpenBLAS: the `update-alternatives` mechanism will take care of things for you, automatically assigning higher priority to the OpenBLAS version of libblas when you install it e.g. with only the ATLAS development packages installed you should see

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep libblas
libblas.so                     auto     /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so
libblas.so.3                   auto     /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3
```

then installing OpenBLAS development packages using

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
```

and checking again you should see

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep libblas
libblas.so                     auto     /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so
libblas.so.3                   auto     /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
```

You should be able to swap between them using `sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so` and following the on-screen instructions.

Comment: i tried them, and it seems it already had this,                                         ih@cap8:~$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep libblas
libblas.so                     auto     /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so
libblas.so.3gf                 auto     /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
ih@cap8:~$ sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
[sudo] password for ih: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libopenblas-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 512 not upgraded.

Comment: ih@cap8:~$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep libblas
libblas.so                     auto     /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so
libblas.so.3gf                 auto     /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0

Comment: But still it has the same error...